# macOS High Sierra / Multiple Versions Java JDK

Tags: java, macos, jenv

I realize there are multiple topics on this over the last 5 years, but I was unable to find something on point so I'm asking for a little help.

My issue is that applications installed on macOS don't seem to find the correct Java (Java 8) that they need because I have multiple versions of the JDK installed for development.  Below is my configuration:

- 2017 Macbook Pro
- macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6
- Homebrew installed JDK 8 and 10
- Jenv installed for managing Java versions

  - Export plug-in to allow jenv to set JAVA_HOME

Sequence:

- I run `jenv global 1.8`
- I have verified that `echo $JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the correct JDK 8.
- When I attempt to run an application like [SQLWorkbenchJ](http://www.sqlworkbench.net) it only sees Java 10 and fails to run.

Anyone have any ideas how to have installed applications use Java 8, but still be able to use Java 10 for dev etc?

Thanks

Comment: How are you _running_ the application? You may need to log out and then back in for environment changes to apply to your current desktop profile.

Comment: I'm running the application from the icon in the /Applications folder.  Unfortunately logout and login didn't help.

Comment: Maybe try start `SQLWorkbenchJ` from command line where you run `jenv global 1.8`